# No Output Received When Flink Streaming Execution Environment Passed With Custom Configuration

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm running Apache Flink version 1.12.7 and configured Streaming Execution Environment with number of task slots for task manager = 3 (just experimenting) but unable to see the output of a file read by the environment. Instead, as seen in the logs, the Execution Graph is stuck as SCHEDULED and does not get into RUNNING state.

Note that if no configuration is passed in the properties file, everything works good and output is seen as environment is able to read the file since Execution Graph get switched to RUNNING state.

The code is as follows :

```
    ParameterTool parameters = ParameterTool.fromPropertiesFile("src/main/resources/application.properties");
    Configuration config = Configuration.fromMap(parameters.toMap());
    TaskExecutorResourceUtils.adjustForLocalExecution(config);

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
            StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(config);

    System.out.println("Config Params : " + config.toMap());

    DataStream<String> inputStream =
            env.readTextFile(FILEPATH);

    DataStream<String> filteredData = inputStream.filter((String value) -> {
        String[] tokens = value.split(",");
        return Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]) >= 75.0;
    });

    filteredData.print(); // no o/p seen if configuration object is set otherwise everything works as expected

    env.execute("Filter Country Details");
```

Need help in understanding this behaviour and what changes should be made in order that the output gets printed along with having some custom configuration. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay..So found the answer to the above puzzle by referring to some links mentioned below.

**Solution** : So I set the parallelism (env.setParallelism) in the above code just after configuring the streaming execution environment and the file was read with output generated as expected.

Post that, experimented with a few things :

- set parallelism equal to number of task slots = everything worked
- set parallelism greater than number of task slots = intermittent results
- set parallelism less than number of task slots = intermittent results.

As per this [link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/concepts/flink-architecture/#task-slots-and-resources) corresponding to Flink Architecture,

> A Flink cluster needs exactly as many task slots as the highest parallelism used in the job

So its best to go with no. of task slots for a task manager equal to the parallelism configured.